# Unhide row of cells with a button

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to unhide a a couple rows of cells (9:18) on a certain worksheet in a workbook via a button.

The only thing I've been able to find online is how to create a toggle button that hides and unhides the cells but I just want the button to be able to unhide them.

Comment: Have you tried removing the "toggling" logic to only keep the part that un-hides rows? What's the code like? Feel free to [edit] your question to include the code you're using. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First off you will need to write a short little VB code that hides these rows. The below example might help you get started, but it is designed to toggle the state of the hidden cells (i.e. if they are currently hidden, then they will become visible)

```
Sub HideRows(Row_Range As Variant, Sheet As Variant)
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets(Sheet)
    'If you do not want a toggle effect, then simply remove this if statement
    If ws.Rows(Row_Range).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Rows(Row_Range).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        ws.Rows(Row_Range).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Once you have added the above to a VBA module in excel, then you can simply call it with the below.

```
Sub Test()

    Call HideRows("12:18", "Sheet1")

End Sub
```

Once you have setup your "Call" macro, then you will need to assign this macro to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a basic macro that will hide/unhide these rows on the activesheet. After putting this into your VBE Code Module, assign this macro to a button. If you don't know how to do that, search on youtube (or wherever you're comfortable) "*how to assign a macro to an excel button*."

```
Sub HideUnhideSomeRows()

    Dim FirstRowToHide As Long: FirstRowToHide = 9  'update these to change the start row
    Dim LastRowToHide As Long: LastRowToHide = 18   'update these to change the end row

    'using the WITH statement reduces the amount of code needed
    With Range(Rows(FirstRowToHide), Rows(LastRowToHide))

        'this if statement only checks the FirstRowToHide but that should work if they all should be grouped.
        If .Hidden = False Then
            .Hidden = True
        Else
           .Hidden = False
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Hope that works. Maybe post some code a little or some screenshots on your next question.